# Camera calibration without chess boards corners

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to make camera calibration.I am following this tutorial :http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html. My problem is:the code doesnt work without ChesseBoardsCorners, and I need to use my own Images. How can I do that?
Thanks fot the Attention

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Do you mean that you want to use your own checkerboard calibration images? What do you mean "doesn't work without ChessBoardCorners" ?

Comment: I mean that the Images I have don't have chessboard. Because of that, the function FindChessBoardsCorners returns false always,and this gives an error on tje function Cameracalibration.

Answer (score 1):

According to [OpenCV 3.1.0 camera calibration documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d94/tutorial_camera_calibration.html), currently OpenCV supports three types of objects for calibration:

1. Classical black-white chessboard
2. Symmetrical circle pattern
3. Asymmetrical circle pattern

It's because, quoting older OpenCV docs, "The coordinates of 3D object points and their corresponding 2D projections in each view must be specified. That may be achieved by using an object with a known geometry and easily detectable feature points. Such an object is called a calibration rig or calibration pattern, and OpenCV has built-in support for a chessboard as a calibration rig.

References for calibration algorithms:
Z. Zhang. A Flexible New Technique for Camera Calibration. IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence, 22(11):1330-1334, 2000.

J.Y.Bouguet. MATLAB calibration tool. (http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/)